# How to use save() Eloquent method on association table between many to many tables?

Tags: mysql, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a association table between tblItems and tblUsers called 'tblItems_Users' but in this table there are also 3 properties besides the 2 foreign keys (FK_item_id and FK_user_id) . Now I am trying to update these properties but I am getting a

Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException (E_UNKNOWN)
HELP
**Call to undefined method stdClass::save()**

Here is the function in my controller where the bug happens :

```
public function checkFirstName($itemId)
    {
      $item = DB::table('tblItems_Users')->where('FK_item_id', '=', $itemId)
      ->where('FK_user_id', '=', Auth::user()->PK_user_id)
      ->first();

      $item->is_checked = 1;
      $item->name_1_checked = 1;

      $item->save();

      return Redirect::route('game');   

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query Builder or the DB::table statement doesn't have save() method. You need to use Eloquent instead.

Create a new Eloquent class inside your models folder if you haven't already:

```
class ItemUser extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'tblItems_Users';
}
```

Use eloquent for the query

```
$item = ItemUser::where('FK_item_id', '=', $itemId)
      ->where('FK_user_id', '=', Auth::user()->PK_user_id)
      ->first();

$item->is_checked = 1;
$item->name_1_checked = 1;
$item->save();
```